# Synchronization algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Basically I need to synchronize two folder/file structures when both folders and files get moved around and changed quite often. They both have history of changes recorded and deltas can be queried by request. I already have some as I think reliable self-made sync algorithm tuned on the go when a problem arises. I was wondering if there is a mathematical background to this problem and probably some well-build theories and patterns I could reuse and improve my system.

Comment: What's the matter with [`rsync`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)?

Comment: The theory behind rsync is even described on Wikipedia. Nice search skills there, @aloneguid. :)

Comment: thanks, let me try, probably was searching for a wrong keyword ;(

Comment: that's not exactly what I wanted. Rsync specifies the optimal way to sync two binary files, not tree structures such as in case of files/folders

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but perhaps [Longest common subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) which is the base of [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) programs: find out what is the difference between two states (ie. folders/files in your case) and encode the sequence of operations that translate state A into state B (what files need to be added, modified and removed for the two location to have the same structure). This kind of solution works if one of the locations is the 'golden' copy (or 'master') and the other one is 'slave': the slave has to reach the state of the master. When the situation is master-master (both sites accept writes) then is significantly more difficult to resolve it, and you need some sort of automated conflict resolution.